# Why does Perl show an "Uncaught exception from user code" line here?

Tags: perl

Learning Perl here.

I am using Strawberry Perl 5 version 22.

I have this script that is supposed to ask for a password, and tell if I got the right password or go away, and when I type in a wrong password, I get this warning "**uncaught exception from user code**"

My script is:

```
#!D:/perl/perl/bin/perl.exe -wT
# Script name = password.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $password = "foxtrot";
print "Enter password: ";
my $guess = <STDIN>;
chomp $guess;
if  ($password eq $guess) {
    print "Pass, friend.\n";
}
if ($password ne $guess) {
    die "Go away! imposter!\n";
}
```

When I enter any word that is not foxtrot, I get:

```
Uncaught exception from user code
Go away! imposter!
```

Why do I get that line "uncaught exception from user code"?

Comment: How are you running this script? This message is likely added by whatever environment you're running the code in.

Comment: @melpomene: I don't think that's true. He already mentioned what his environment is. My environment (GNU/Linux) is different from his Windows-based Strawberry Perl setup and I was still able to easily reproduce the behavior. Please see the docs on `die`, which mentions it raises an exception. His code is clearly not handling it, hence the message. Please see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603570/why-does-perl-show-an-uncaught-exception-from-user-code-line-here/33603629#33603629) for more info.

Comment: @ray I wasn't asking about about the environment. But I was indeed missing the `use diagnostics` line. Sorry about the distraction.

Answer (score 4):

> ***Why do I get that line "uncaught exception from user code"?***

It is because you loaded the [diagnostics](https://metacpan.org/pod/diagnostics) module with `use diagnostics`. It is annotating warnings and errors with explanations, in this case your call to `die`.

```
$ perl -wle 'die "foo"'
foo at -e line 1.

$ perl -wle 'use diagnostics; die "foo"'
Uncaught exception from user code:
    foo at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception message is caused by the `die` function call in combination with the loaded `diagnostics` module, which adds more verbose information.

You should consider using the following instead:

```
print "Go away! Imposter!\n";
exit 1;
```

Quoting from the [Perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html), my emphasis added:

> `die` **raises an exception**. Inside an eval the error message is stuffed
>   into `$@` and the `eval` is terminated with the undefined value. **If the
>   exception is outside of all enclosing evals, then the uncaught
>   exception prints `LIST` to `STDERR` and exits with a non-zero value.** If
>   you need to exit the process with a specific exit code, see exit.

Your `die` call is outside eval statements, so it prints the message and exits due to an unhandled exception.

Comment: `die` is perfectly appropriate. Just don't leave `use diagnostics;` in outside of debugging. In fact, you should probably never have `use diagnostics;` in the code. Just use `perl -Mdiagnostics ...` when you want to figure out what a warning means.