# inserting data from xlsx to database by perl

Tags: perl, xlsx

I need to insert data from xlsx to database and this code work only do 2 rows not for all data in file and i need to skip first line cmd told me that I inserting 4 values but 3 is needed but my excel have 3 rows[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuYLv.png)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('test.xlsx');
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:pokus:localhost", "root", "", { RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $query = 'INSERT INTO soucastky (id, name, age, city) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr();


if ( !defined $workbook ) {
       die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
   my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        my @values;
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;
            push @values, $cell->value();
        }
        $sth->execute(@values) or die $dbh->errstr;
    }
}

open my $fh, "<", "test" or die $!;
while (<$fh>)
{
        chomp;
        my @vals = split;
        $sth->execute(@vals);
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603570/why-does-perl-show-an-uncaught-exception-from-user-code-line-here).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation for Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel), you'll see it says:

> The Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module can be used to read information from Excel 95-2003 binary files.
>
> The module cannot read files in the Excel 2007 Open XML XLSX format. See the [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX) module instead.

And the documentation for Spreadsheet::XLSX says:

> This module has some serious issues with the way it uses regexs for parsing the XML. I would strongly encourage switching to [Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX) which takes a more reliable approach.

So you need to switch to a module that can parse the spreadsheets that you're using.